# Relative Layout with a nested Linear Layout inside. How to position the Linear layout at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Relative Layout which has a Photo Gallery and a Media player in it.  My problem is I want the media player controls (pause/play/forward/rewind) 4 buttons to be positioned at the bottom of the screen while maintaining its center horizontal alignment.  What I did was

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_audio_view"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundimg"
tools:context="com.my.project.LaunchGalleryview">

   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        >
   </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The cuttons inside the Linear Layout are allinged center but the whole Linear Layout is positioned at the center of my screen.  I want it to be at the bottom of the screen.  I already tried andoird:gravity="bottom"  it still positioned center of the screen how can I force it to be at the bottom?

Comment: Why do you use `android:layout_centerInParent` if you want it at the bottom? Why don't you use `alignParentBottom`?

Comment: Very sorry english is not my first language thats why I have difficulty understanding the documentation.  I wanted to maintain the horizontal center alignment thats why I thought that layout_centerInParent will do the job and pull it down to the buttom of the screen using gravity:"bottom".  Which is the whole point of my problem (misunderstood the docu)

Comment: I dont understand why people love to downvote newbie beginner level questions what do this people gain?  Please remember that you were once newbies too and made stupid mistakes and misunderstood apis too.  Also not everyone has english for its first language.  Last time I checked this is a community helping each other I did not know that newbies are not welcome to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Use

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" <!-- Bottom of the RelativeLayout -->
android:gravity="center" <!-- centers all child views within the LinearLayout -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to the LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the Linear layout

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```